# Master pages in ASP.NET

Tags: master-pages

I am new to the field of ASP.NET and need help in this.
I have a master page with user controls on it. But to display one of the control, the user should first go and read the contents of a text file, if the content of file is 1 then display the control else display an error message. How can I do this in master pages.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not a database? Also, use the codebehind file

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to keep the control flow on the master page, or can you move it to a page that uses the master page? the reason I ask is it sounds like you have a workflow where the user accepts reading the text and then gets content. If I am correct, that is an issue best handled in the page and not in the master page.

Master pages are best used for content that appears on multiple pages, perhaps all pages of the site. Menus come to mind, as does all of the "chrome" (graphics, etc.) that make your site "your site".

Individual pages are best used for user interaction type issues, except perhaps prefences (I want the page in pink, not blue - bad example, as there are better ways to handle this, but it paints a picture).

Comment: The control need to be displayed accordingly in all the pages depending on the condition. So have to keep the control flow on the master page.